# Are there natural selection experiments that quantitatively agree with theoretical modeling?

Tags: evolution, mathematical-models, theoretical-biology, experimental

Has anyone ever conducted an evolution experiment and quantitatively compared it to theory?  For example, has anyone ever put bacteria in a million petri dishes filled with antibiotics and calculated the number of petri dishes that should develop drug-resistant bacteria, and then compared that calculation with the experiment?

I imagine that both the experiment and theoretical modeling would be very difficult, but maybe someone has been ambitious enough to try it.

Comment: If this is possible, I'd be particularly interested in finding out what variables they took into account in their calculations.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the theoretical model would be. But really, I just wanted to say that you might enjoy reading about the Luria-Delbruck fluctuation experiment, which is tangentially relevant - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luria%E2%80%93Delbr%C3%BCck_

Comment: The question is definitely unclear. There are tons of theoretical predictions. The vast majority of them have been tested (sometimes through experimental evolution ans sometimes through observation) but not all.

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest example to this is Greg Lang's work at Princeton. His work will take a population of yeast and let it grow for 1000 generations. At each generation a sample will be kept allowing sequencing of the population at each generation.
His website is available here: http://www.genomics.princeton.edu/glang/

And some of his work has already been published here: http://www.genomics.princeton.edu/glang/papers.htm

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am not getting the example you give, it seems to me that there is a classic experiment that does just what you said:  the fluctuation test or the [luria-delbruck experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luria%E2%80%93Delbr%C3%BCck_experiment)

Also, [this recent paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24231808) from R. Lenski's lab is a good example too.

but I am sure there must be others.